# I can't seem to debug my code can anyone help me?

Tags: angular, angular5

I'm trying to create a view detail function for my angular app.

I've tried searching on google on how to solve my error but none of the current solutions work for me.

> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MovieDetailComponent -> MoviesService]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MovieDetailComponent -> MoviesService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for MoviesService!
>   Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MovieDetailComponent -> MoviesService]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MovieDetailComponent -> MoviesService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for MoviesService!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (core.js:8896)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:9141)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:9085)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (core.js:8982)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:21218)
>       at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:21907)
>       at resolveDep (core.js:22278)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
>       at zone.js:892
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)

Comment: Please share the `app.module.ts` code

Comment: Please try to follow the rules for asking questions on Stack Overflow. Your error tells you exactly what is wrong: you are not providing MoviesService. Either add it to the providers array of the corresponding module, or follow @AlleXyS answer below and add the `providedIn` attribute to the `@Injectable` decorator.

Comment: alright sorry about that I'll post questions according to the rules next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service, must have the decorator ahead of class declaration

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

This will inject the service in your app (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)